# Is there a difference between normal Duvel and Duvel "Love"

Tags: distribution

I bought a 4-pack of Duvel recently and when I looked at the last bottle I saw that instead of this label:

[image: Standard Duvel label with large red "Duvel"]

It instead had this label:

[image: Smaller red "Duvel" with larger carved-wood styled "love" text.]

All of the bottles had different art/text on the backs, but up to this point I hadn't noticed anything different on the front label, so I decided to look into it.

I couldn't find any official references to a Duvel "love" beer but also could not find any official images of these labels.  I was able to find images of bottles with the same label [listed as a unique beer on Untappd](https://untappd.com/b/duvel-love/1158848) but am somewhat hesitant to take this as any kind of proof of it being a different beer.

Did I stumble upon a rarity or packaging mistake or is this the same beer and I'm just overreacting because I don't know any better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't even show on the belgian (dutch/french) pages of the site, My best guess is that it's just an alternate cover.

[DUVEL - mastery in beer](http://www.duvel.com/en-us/the-beer/duvel)

It seems they used these different covers as a marketing trick designed to generate publicity and hype as it clearly did here

Comment: That's what I'm thinking, it just seems weird that only one of beers would have a non-standard front label. Especially since all the back labels are easily found. Especially without any sort of explanation, either on the bottle or the Internet.

Comment: Moortgat (the brewer) did announce they were going to permanently change their bottle design they do also 'troll' people by having a different logo on 1 in 1000 bottles"
and this http://www.martinagency.com/work/duvel-labels#

Comment: Can you find any official references to them changing the logo on 1 in 1000 bottles? I'm still amazed that I can't even find a secondary source (e.g. article or blog post) mentioning this label considering there are enough out there for it to show up on Untappd.

Comment: here found it
https://www.beersyndicate.com/app/Place/Details/366
they had a gag were they would replace the devil on the bottle with an angle (duvel ~= devil)

Comment: Ah, interesting. With the other labels there that definitely suggests it is just a part of their current set of differing labels. Can you edit this into your answer?

Comment: but it is never said how and were they are distributed and the changing of the logo would be here https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLkaqsEtlB-yBjFR38mEMsRjx0hsOdeM0H&v=HDjKQpeA2c8